# SQL Database Constraint | Multi-table Constraint

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, constraints

I need to make 2 database constraints that connect two different tables at one time.

### 1. The total score of the four quarters equals the total score of the game the quarters belong to.

### 2. The total point of all the players equals to the score of the game of that team.

Here is what my tables look like.

```
quarter table
+------+--------+--------+--------+   
| gNum | Period | hScore | aScore |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
|    1 |      1 | 13     | 18     |   
|    1 |      2 | 12     | 19     |
|    1 |      3 | 23     | 31     |
|    1 |      4 | 32     | 18     |
|      |        | Total  | Total  |
|      |        | 80     | 86     |
+------+--------+--------+--------+

Game Table
+-----+--------+--------+--------+
| gID | hScore | lScore | tScore |
+-----+--------+--------+--------+
|   1 |     86 |     80 |    166 |
+-----+--------+--------+--------+

Player Table
+-----+------+--------+--------+
| pID | gNum | Period | Points |
+-----+------+--------+--------+
|   1 |    1 |      1 |     20 |
|     |      |      2 |     20 |
|     |      |      3 |     20 |
|     |      |      4 |     20 |
+-----+------+--------+--------+
```

So Virtually I need to use CHECK I think to make sure that players points = score of their team ie (hScore, aScore) and also make sure that the hScore and aScore = the total score in the Game table.

I was thinking of creating a foreign key variable on one of the tables and setting up constraints on that would this be the best way of going about it?

Thanks

Comment: It really depends on how you insert your data into the table, but one idea might be to scrap your current "hscore", "lscore", "tscore" columns and use computed columns with functions to determine whatever you need. e.g. `CREATE TABLE tblGames (gID INT PRIMARY KEY, hScore AS dbo.fn_calculateHScore(gID), lScore AS dbo.fn_calculateLScore(gID), tScore AS dbo.fn_calculateTScore(gID));` and the functions would just return the total values of the quarter table for each respective requirement.

Comment: That said, why do you need to store the score in the games table? You would probably be better off creating a view with said functions if you really require it and not storing the total score in a table. It depends on your needs I guess, but eh.

Comment: I didn't think of that, Our professor just gave us the assignment and wanted to see how everyone went after it... I was thinking of creating separate foreign key constraints is that viable or a waste of time? I like where you are going with the view though! By foreign key constraints I mean create a variable that references hScore and lScore and make tScore have to = the sum of those two..

Comment: You could use some sort of check constraint. What I would do if I were creating these tables is create the player table that has basic information about a player (id, name, dob, whatever), create a game table that has basic information about a game (id, name, perhaps where, etc), then create an event table that records points in a game (with columns like gameid, quarter, playerid, points). I wouldn't bother storing the scores, I'd get that from a basic SUM query against the event table.

Comment: If I couldn't alter the table structures/designs, I think I'd just use functions to calculate everything from the players table, now that I'm looking closer at it. Presumably you have a table somewhere to record who the home team and who the away team was... I'd just create functions that calculates the total scores from the players table alone. The quarter table would be filled with functions to calculate the quarter scores. The game table would just calculate the totals based on the player table alone.

Comment: EDIT: Actually, your "player" table is already kind of like the event table i'm thinking of anyway (except there's no column in the sample data for recording what team they're on). So I'd just query against that or perhaps create a view/stored procedure to do that if I needed to.

Comment: It is an event table it's actually called plays.. I've implemented all the tables already, I just posted the attributes that I need the constraints on. The total of homeTeam and awayTeam scores needs to add up to a total score, which actually isn't an attribute in any table.... so can I create a view and add an attribute to it?? And Everything you said I should have I do have as in player table have their team ID and in the game I have away team home team and then home score and away score in quarter table.

Comment: The total for the home team would just be a sum of all the player scores in the player table, right? e.g. if I wanted to find the total scores for each player in a game, i'd do a sum of the points in the plays table grouped by game and playerid (and quarter if necessary). If I wanted to find the total for a game id just group by game and not playerid. I'd create whatever views/stored procedures/functions you want based on that.

Comment: Awesome thanks man really appreciate it! That makes a lot of sense! we have barely went over functions in class, but I think that's what he wants us to kinda figure out! You've been a big help!